# Receiving query limit error "Request was Running for too long and has been stopped."

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I have batch which queries for record in a standard object which has 16 million of records. I am trying to query only few records with checkbox checked using querylocator to delete it .
However the query takes too long to process and times out.
The query used is "`Select id, Delete_Social_Post__c,xxx_c,ExternalId_c, CreatedDate From SocialPost where Delete_Social_Post__c = true Order by createddate asc` "

Rgds

Comment: instead of `createddate` try with `systemModStamp`

Answer (score 1):

You can improve your performance with selecting indexed fields - you should read about performance patterns like this:

[Improve performance with Custom indexes using Selective SOQL Queries](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006007&language=en_US)

Comment: Hi Itai, I could not make the query more selective. May be i will have to request Salesforce to add custom index to the checkbox field i add in the query. Please let me know if there are any other options for the same

Comment: This is a good option, you can try to narrow down your search first with an indexed column, see if it helps, then change it back

Comment: Using selective queries is THE best option but in the event of this not being possible, you could also use LIMIT/OFFSET to show limited number of records and then query more assuming this is happening on a VF page.